# Paginated Comments “reply” does not work!

Tags: plugins, php, comments, comments-template, paginate-comments-links

I use plugin Paginated Comments. I edit template and CSS in paginated-comments.php but "reply" does not work. "reply" does not appear at all.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vl5r6.jpg (There should be a button to reply).

Code full: http://pastebin.com/70Aq4fEQ

What is problem? Help me please, thanks

```
<div id="respond">

        <h3><?php comment_form_title( __('Yorum Yap', 'wpzoom' ), __('Leave a Reply to %s', 'wpzoom')); ?></h3>

        <div class="cancel-comment-reply"><p><?php cancel_comment_reply_link(); ?></p></div>

            <?php if ( get_option('comment_registration') && !$user_ID ) : ?>

            <p><?php _e('You must be', 'wpzoom') ?> <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-login.php?redirect_to=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()); ?>"><?php _e('logged in', 'wpzoom') ?></a> <?php _e('to post a comment.', 'wpzoom') ?></p>
            <?php else : ?> 

        <form action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform">

        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" tabindex="1" rows="10" cols="140"></textarea><br />

            <?php if ( $user_ID ) : ?>

            <p><?php _e('Logged in as', 'wpzoom') ?> <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-admin/profile.php"><?php echo $user_identity; ?></a>. <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e('Log out of this account', 'wpzoom') ?>"><?php _e('Logout', 'wpzoom') ?> &raquo;</a></p>       

 <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="comm-submit" value="<?php _e('Yorum Gönder', 'wpzoom') ?>" />    

            <?php else : ?>

                <div id="formLabels">

                    <p><input type="text" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '<?php _e('İsim (gerekli)', 'wpzoom') ?>';}" onfocus="if (this.value == '<?php _e('İsim (gerekli)', 'wpzoom') ?>') {this.value = '';}" value="<?php _e('İsim (gerekli)', 'wpzoom') ?>" name="author" id="author"  size="4" tabindex="2" <?php if ($req) echo "aria-required='true'"; ?> /></p>

                    <p><input type="text" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '<?php _e('Email (yayınlanmayacak)', 'wpzoom') ?>';}" onfocus="if (this.value == '<?php _e('Email (yayınlanmayacak)', 'wpzoom') ?>') {this.value = '';}" value="<?php _e('Email (yayınlanmayacak)', 'wpzoom') ?>" name="email" id="email" size="4" tabindex="3" <?php if ($req) echo "aria-required='true'"; ?> /> </p>

                    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="comm-submit" value="<?php _e('Yorum Gönder', 'wpzoom') ?>" />

                </div>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php comment_id_fields(); ?>

            <?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>

        <div class="clear"></div>

        </form>

    <?php endif; // If registration required and not logged in ?>
```

Comment: First of all you talk about a plugin you want help for (wrong place try [here](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/paginated-comments) ). Another issue which actualy is even more important about that specific plugin.. Last Updated: 6 years ago ... , hope you are sure that it is clear code and compatible with Wordpress 4.*.* . _That plugin **was** compatible up to  Wordpress 2.8.* !!!_ If you think you need a plugin for such please take another look at the wp plugin [directory](https://wordpress.org/plugins/).

Comment: Thanks but Do not fix this plugin? or Can you update? I need this plugin.Maybe the problem can be solved with PHP. Just "reply" does not work, do not have any problems. Not an plugin like this, I've tried them all.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you don't need the plug-in to break your comments into pages. This can be done by default, you have to chose and set some settings according to your needs though. You will find the according settings section under »*Settings > Discussion > Other comment settings > "Break comments into pages.."*« in your WordPress' admin area.

Comment: Thanks, I know that setting but I want more different paging. So, I need this plugin.

Comment: Titles for each page of comments.
Description and Keywords for each pages of comments.
Paginate by size of all comments.
Personalize your Pretty Permalinks URI's.
Control page of comments post content.

Comment: Ok, then your question is still off topic, besides, consider what [charles said in his comment](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213961/paginated-comments-reply-does-not-work/214065?noredirect=1#comment311427_213961). @cem

Comment: My question is not off topic. Wordpress, plugins and PHP knowledge is required.

Comment: Please take another look at the guidelines about »[What topics can I ask about here?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)«. I think, you will see that I'm right. @cem